# ASP.net StoreFront WSI Interface 400 Bad Request

Tags: http, soap, aspdotnetstorefront

So I fixed a couple of errors that were being spit out, now all I'm getting is an HTTP 400, anyone have any idea what's wrong? Or any ideas on how to get more information? I'm not an experienced windows admin or experienced with ASP.net StoreFront.

```
< POST http://192.168.122.3/ASPDNSF0/ipx.asmx
User-Agent: libwww-perl/6.05
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset="utf-8"
SOAPAction: "http://www.aspdotnetstorefront.com/DoItUsernamePwd"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <soap12:Body>
    <DoItUsernamePwd xmlns="http://www.aspdotnetstorefront.com/">
      <AuthenticationEMail>admin@aspdotnetstorefront.com</AuthenticationEMail>
      <AuthenticationPassword>Admin$11</AuthenticationPassword>
      <XmlInputRequestString>
        <ASPDotNetStorefrontImport Version="9.2">
          <Product action="Add">
            <Name>my product name</Name>
            <SKU>1234</SKU>
            <Description><![CDATA[please
add some <b>data</b>]]></Description>
          </Product>
        </ASPDotNetStorefrontImport>
      </XmlInputRequestString>
    </DoItUsernamePwd>
  </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>

> HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Cache-Control: private
Date: Tue, 17 Sep 2013 23:06:04 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.0
Content-Type: text/html
Client-Date: Tue, 17 Sep 2013 21:06:04 GMT
Client-Peer: 192.168.122.3:80
Client-Response-Num: 1
Client-Transfer-Encoding: chunked
X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET

Bad Request
```

Comment: Why do you feel this is a programming problem?

Comment: because I'm integrating with a web service. It's almost definitely a problem with my code.

Comment: But you didn't _show_ any code. Also, the problem could be with the service, and not with your code. It could also be a simple data problem. For instance, is the SKU meant to be unique? Maybe that SKU already exists.

Comment: This is a fresh install, nothing exists in the system. HTTP and XML are code. Showing you the code that is simply creating this XML/HTTP would be noise. This is a question about the web service itself. Asking a question about a webservice API is equally as valid as asking about a native .net API.

Comment: Well, good luck. Does the same call work with other SKUs? Do other calls work? Does an "edit" of a product work?

Comment: call does not work at all (outside of transmission)

Comment: But other calls _do_ work? See how I'm trying to narrow it down?

Comment: @JohnSaunders honestly I just think you're being a <explitive>. Keep in mind I'm a moderator on Unix SE. I'm trying to figure out how to make an under documented API that throws really undescriptprive errors, and doesn't appear to be logging details anywhere, out. Right now I suspect I simply need to send more fields, but I could be completely wrong. If you don't use this API then you probably aren't going to be of any help, because you know about as much about it as I do. I've never made any of this API work. I've been "reducing"? the number of errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is that it's basically a full sub XML document embedded in request, fully escaped. Also had a couple of elements slightly off `AspDotNetStorefrontImport`.

```
POST http://192.168.122.3/ASPDNSF0/ipx.asmx
User-Agent: libwww-perl/6.05
Content-Length: 1368
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset="utf-8"
SOAPAction: "DoItUsernamePwd"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <soap12:Body>
    <DoItUsernamePwd xmlns="http://www.aspdotnetstorefront.com/">
      <AuthenticationEMail>admin@aspdotnetstorefront.com</AuthenticationEMail>
      <AuthenticationPassword>Admin$11</AuthenticationPassword>
      <XmlInputRequestString>&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?&gt;
&lt;AspDotNetStorefrontImport Version="9.2"&gt;
  &lt;Entity Action="Add" EntityType="Manufacturer"&gt;
    &lt;Name&gt;Nike&lt;/Name&gt;
    &lt;Address1&gt;something lane&lt;/Address1&gt;
    &lt;Address2&gt;somewhere&lt;/Address2&gt;
    &lt;City&gt;Austin&lt;/City&gt;
    &lt;State&gt;TX&lt;/State&gt;
    &lt;ZipCode&gt;78752&lt;/ZipCode&gt;
    &lt;Country&gt;United States&lt;/Country&gt;
    &lt;Published&gt;false&lt;/Published&gt;
    &lt;Phone&gt;1112223333&lt;/Phone&gt;
    &lt;FAX&gt;1112223333&lt;/FAX&gt;
    &lt;Description&gt;&lt;![CDATA[athletic manufactuer]]&gt;&lt;/Description&gt;
    &lt;Display&gt;
      &lt;XMLPackage&gt;entity.gridwithprices.xml.config&lt;/XMLPackage&gt;
    &lt;/Display&gt;
  &lt;/Entity&gt;
&lt;/AspDotNetStorefrontImport&gt;
</XmlInputRequestString>
    </DoItUsernamePwd>
  </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
```